# client template kendo ui asp net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a grid with a `Client_Name column`, but I want pass the ID to another view, an put the link to this view in the `Client_Name column`.

In  the next instruction, how I can set to `ITEM_ID` the value of the ID in the row.

```
columns
.Bound(e => .Desc_Cliente)
.Width(120)
.Groupable(false)
.Title("Descripcion")
.ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("ClientProfile_GeneralData", "CrmCProfile", new { Id_Cliente = ITEM_ID }) + "/#= Id_Cliente #'" + ">#= Desc_Cliente #</a>");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `#: #` notation:

```
columns
.Bound(e => .Desc_Cliente)
.Width(120)
.Groupable(false)
.Title("Descripcion")
.ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("ClientProfile_GeneralData", "CrmCProfile", new { Id_Cliente = "#: Id_Cliente #" }) + "'>#= Desc_Cliente #</a>");
```

Even though the ID may not be a string, don't forget that the `Url.Action` converts the whole thing into a string anyway. MVC will take care of the casting internally.

Another way to do this is with the `@Html.ActionLink` helper:

```
.ClientTemplate(
    @Html.ActionLink("#= Desc_Cliente #", "ClientProfile_GeneralData", "CrmCProfile", 
        new { Id_Cliente = "#: Id_Cliente #" }, 
        null
    ).ToHtmlString()
)
```

For what it's worth, I haven't figured out yet the difference between `#: #` and `#= #`. Either one seems to work.

Comment: #= # Renders values as HTML  
#: # Uses HTML encoding  

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview